# OnEdit Trigger for a cell to Save and Clear Data that functions on an iPads

Tags: triggers

I was hoping someone could help me. I'm not a coder or IT guy, youtube is my friend but I can't find an OnEdit trigger that activates some existing code that works for buttons on an ipad, I know its possible to do an OnEdit trigger for a specific cell that triggers from a Drop down but they seem limited. I wasn't sure if I could have the trigger work for saving a range and clearing data. Here is the code.

```
function saveRecord(e) { 

 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

 const formWS = ss.getSheetByName("Form")
 const settingsWS = ss.getSheetByName("Settings")
 const dataWS = ss.getSheetByName("Data")

 const idCell = formWS.getRange("G3")

 const fieldRange =             ["G5","G7","G10","G12","H12","G16","G18","G22","G24","H24","G28","G30","G34","G36"]

 const fieldValues = fieldRange.map (f => formWS.getRange(f).getValue())

 const nextIDCell = settingsWS.getRange("A2")
 const nextID = nextIDCell.getValue()

 fieldValues.unshift(nextID)

 //console.log (fieldValues)
 dataWS.appendRow(fieldValues)
 idCell.setValue(nextID)
 nextIDCell.setValue(nextID+1)


 }

function Clear() {
fieldRange.forEach(f => formWS.getRange(f).clearContent())
idCell.clearContent()
}
```